# Why use folder.close() instead of directly using store.close()?

Tags: jakarta-mail

From what i managed to understand if you directly use store.close() without using first the method`folder.close(expungeYesOrNo)` then you will not be able to delete messages marked for the deletion and  ConnectionListeners for that folder will not be activated because a CLOSED COnnectionEvent will not be sent. Is this correct? Any additions?

Thank you in advance

EDIT:  Upon closer inspection of IMAPStore.cleanup(), i see  Folder.close(false) is called for each folder opened..so then this bit of code `emailFolder.close(false) /* this one*/; emailStore.close();` would be redundant right?  (taken from http://www.javatpoint.com/example-of-receiving-email-using-java-mail-api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing the Store should close all the Folders as well, but it's more of an "abrupt" closure than the controlled closure you get by calling Folder.close.

If you know when you're done with the folder and can close it, that will be more reliable and predictable than just forgetting about the folder and assuming store.close will take care of it. Yes, closing the store will attempt to close all the folders, but if you've looked at that code and seen how it's evolved over many releases, you'll know it's complicated and error prone. I'd like to believe it's correct and reliable now, but I've been wrong before...

Answer (score 1):

If you close the entire store, you can't do anything else to the store afterwards. Surely this is obvious? If you just close the folder, you can't do anything more to the folder, but you can still operate on the store.

Comment: yes but is it bad practice if i close the store directly without calling folder.close()?will any problems appear?...in the javadoc for store.close() it says that "Any Messaging components (Folders, Messages, etc.) belonging to this service are invalid after this service is closed"

Comment: Closing the Store should close all the Folders as well, but it's more of an "abrupt" closure than the controlled closure you get by calling Folder.close.

Comment: If you know when you're done with the folder and can close it, that will be more reliable and predictable than just forgetting about the folder and assuming store.close will take care of it.  Yes, closing the store will attempt to close all the folders, but if you've looked at that code and seen how it's evolved over many releases, you'll know it's complicated and error prone.  I'd like to believe it's correct and reliable now, but I've been wrong before...

Comment: @BillShannon post your 2 comments as an answer and i'll accept it.